# How to specify multiple Dataframe type variables in the for loop? (Python Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pybithumb

bithumb_list = ['BTC', 'ETH', 'XRP', 'ADA']

for coin in bithumb_list:
   df = pybithumb.get_ohlcv(coin)
```

Here, the dataframe type value is stored in df.
Eventually, the dataframe values are stored in df four times around the for loop.
But I want the df variable name to be different as below every time the for loop turns, how can I implement it?

Help me.

```
df1 = pybithumb.get_ohlcv('BTC')
df2 = pybithumb.get_ohlcv('ETH')
df3 = pybithumb.get_ohlcv('XRP')
df4 = pybithumb.get_ohlcv('ADA')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can gather all your dataframes in a dictionairy, where you store your dataframe name as the key:

```
df_dict = {}
for coin in bithumb_list:
   df_dict[f'df_{coin}'] = pybithumb.get_ohlcv(coin)
```

To select the BTC dataframe you simply select it from the df_dict:

```
df_dict['df_BTC']
```